# Why is my numerical scheme for heat equation unstable?

Tags: numerical-methods, stability-theory

I've got an inhomogeneous heat equation at hand:
$$\partial_tu=\alpha\partial_x^2u+f(t,x).$$
I discretised it according to the [FTCS scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTCS_scheme), i. e. I applied the forward Euler method for $\partial_t$ and twice the central difference for $\partial_x^2$:
$$u^{n+1,m}=u^{n,m}+r\Big(u^{n,m+2}-2u^{n,m}+u^{n,m-2}\Big),$$
where $r\equiv\frac{\alpha\Delta t}{(2\Delta x)^2}$ and $u^{n,m}\equiv u(n\Delta t,m\Delta x)$.

Note that the central space difference is taken over double the lattice spacing ($4\Delta x$ instead of $2\Delta x$) in my case, compared to the standard scheme. This is because I need to calculate the first and the second derivative w. r. t. $x$ separately.

**My problem:** The solution shows (not-so-)slight disturbances of small wavelength, see the pictures attached: The first solution should look as on the second one.
        [image]      [image]

**My idea:** The stability condition on the step sizes is
$$\left|1-4r\sin^2\left(k\Delta x\right)\right|\leq1\;\forall\;k,$$
where $k$ is the wave number of the solution. When I plot the left hand side against $k$, one can see that regardless of my choice of $r$, there are always values of $k$ for which the condition is only *marginally* fulfilled (i. e. where the left hand side is equal to $1$; **red dots**).

[image]

May this be the source of the instability?

**Annotations:**

I need to compute the first derivative $\partial_xu$ separately since I'd like to manipulate it in the future before taking the second derivative. So, my routine actually looks like this:

$$u^{n,m+1}=u^{n,m}-\frac{\Delta t}{2\Delta x}\Big(v^{n,m+1}-v^{n,m-1}\Big)\\
v^{n,m}=-\frac{\alpha}{2\Delta x}\Big(u^{n,m+1}-u^{n,m-1}\Big)$$

At the boundaries $m\in\{0,M\}$ I take $u=0$ and $v$ is calculated with the forward/backward difference method rather than the central difference:

$$u^{n,0}=u^{n,M}=0\\
v^{n,0}=\frac{\alpha}{\Delta x}\Big(u^{n,1}-u^{n,0}\Big)\\
v^{n,M}=\frac{\alpha}{\Delta x}\Big(u^{n,M}-u^{n,M-1}\Big)$$

Fully expanded, this amounts to the scheme:
$$u^{n+1,m}=\begin{cases}0&m\in\{0,M\},\\
u^{n,1}+2r\Big(u^{n,2}-2u^{n,1}+u^{n,0}\Big)&m=1,\\
u^{n,M-1}+2r\Big(u^{n,M}-2u^{n,M-1}+u^{n,M-2}\Big)&m=M-1,\\
u^{n,m}+r\Big(u^{n,m+2}-2u^{n,m}+u^{n,m-2}\Big)&\mathrm{else}\\\end{cases}$$

Comment: how did you choose $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$? Does your choice satisfy the CFL condition of your problem?

Comment: Are your disturbances actually at small wavelengths or are they just at every other node? Also, how do you set boundary conditions for the even/odd set of nodes where the boundary is not embedded in the grid? I suspect this is causing some issue. Just use the standard method and interpolate to compute your first derivative when you need it.

Comment: @G.Gare The step sizes are taken according to the condition in my post, which is fulfilled if $r\leq\frac{1}{2}\Leftrightarrow\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}r\Delta t}\leq\Delta x$.

Comment: @whpowell96 Seems to be that the disturbance is indeed oscillating between every other node. What might that hint at? I chose the boundaries to be zero, and the next-to-boundary nodes are calculated with another difference method. I'm going to make an amendment to my original post to illustrate that.

Comment: It hints at the fact that you are solving the heat equation on two grids with two sets of boundary conditions and expecting them to interleaf perfectly. The boundary conditions for the offset grid are likely inaccurate and these errors are propogating through all of that grid's nodes

Comment: Thank you! I've added some detail on my algorithm now in my post. What do you mean by the "offset grid"? I can't see where I might be using mismatching boundary conditions.

Comment: $u^m$ depends only on $u^{m+2}$ and $u^{m-2}$. Therefore the solutions $u^0$, $u^2$, ... and $u^1$, $u^3$, ... are only related by the boundary condition scheme you've set up, which is a likely source of error even in a traditional grid